# Какая архитектура кода правильная в laravel?

Tags: laravel

Всем привет. Изучаю laravel и возник вот какой вопрос, подскажите опытные программисты, как правильно организовать код в Laravel?

Объясню, что имею ввиду. Сейчас смотрю уроки, читаю стать и заметил такую тенденцию, всё просто, регистрируешь путь, к нему подключаешь контроллер, при необходимости вешаешь middleware, а дальше в контроллере пишешь логику, например выгружаешь из БД данные о пользователе и возвращаешь результат в blade, распихивая по шаблону результат ответа... Т.е. практически во всех уроках код обработчика пишется в контроллере... Не так давно приходил представитель компании в учебное заведение и сказал, что писать обработку запроса в самом контроллере не правильно, если обработчик объемный, то это очень плохо, потому что в контроллере много методов и дальнейшая поддержка приложения будет затруднительна. И сказал, лучше обработчик выносить в отдельный класс, а в контроллере вызывать методы этого класса и возвращать результат, но не писать сам обработчик в контроллере...

Я вот не понимаю, как это сделать? Есть какой то инструмент для написания обработчиков в Laravel? Или это вообще чисто сами разработчики решают как назвать директорию, там создавать файлы с классами и описывать обработку там... Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше и правильней построить архитектуру кода в Laravel?

Comment: Ну смотря что Вы имеете ввиду под обработкой. Если валидация и возможно что какая-то определенная трансформация данных, то это делается в [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#form-request-validation), сам по себе контроллер должен быть тонким. В зависимости от того что Вы имеете ввиду, обычно есть "место" куда эту "экстра" логику можно вынести. Есть неплохая [статья](https://laraveldaily.com/post/laravel-structure-services-actions-eloquent) и еще есть удобный [cheat sheet](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices/tree/master) с рядом лучших практик.

Comment: По статье, не долистал до конца, она платная, но по оглавлению можно нагуглить то что там описывается.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/articles/424595/

Comment: пишите вы пока что как вы удобно, пусть даже это будет толстый контроллер. Если придете к осознанию того, что контроллер стал слишком тяжелым, смешивает разные задачи и т.п -> настало время декомпозиции и разделения ответственности, сначала, возможно, весь рабочий код в какой-то сервис-класс, потом возможно декомпозиция этого класса на разные.  Если проект простой и легкий нет смысла плодить сотни классов просто ради разделения чего-то.

Comment: @user7860670 вообще не в тему ссылка..ТС, ищите на ютуб канал "Просто о Laravel. CutCode", конкретно по вашему вопросу - на канале ищите "Куда вынести логику из controllers"

Comment: @teran плохой совет. Контроллер должен только принимать запрос и возвращать ответ, вся логика остальная - не его зона ответственности

Comment: Архитектура приложения - это прям отдельная дисциплина, в двух словах не расскажешь. Вкратце - максимально разделяйте логику, не строчите все в одном классе, изучите паттерны, разберитесь минимально в популярных архитектурах (DDD, слоеная архитектура, гексоганальная, сервисный слой и т.п.), ну и  нарабатывайте практику)

Answer (score 1):

Начну с того что `laravel` дает огромную вазможность писаь код разными стилями.

Правильно сказано что весь код нельзя писать в контроллере. Да и вообще правильно всегда делить большой код на части (методы - функции). Что бы четко понять какой метод что делает.
После этого потом разобрать код будет проще. И второе можно использовать те же методы в разных местах, если есть тому нужда.

Я пишу кода примерно так.

1. В контроллере основная бизнес логика приложения.
2. Есть разные сервисы (`Services`) в которых можно писать большую часть логики для приложения.
3. Все что касается напрямую работы с базой данных, для этого есть репозитории (`Repository`). Для каждой модели есть репозитория. И если нужно работать с этой моделью оно делается через репозиторий.

Вот сам 3-ий пункт по моему правильно. Потому что оснавная логика приложения вообще не связана с базой данных, и если вдруг нужно будет менять базу данных, или добавить другую (например вместо `MySql` внедрить другую), то логика приложения не меняется. Просто нужно будет добавить репозитории для новой базы данных.

Вот первая попавшая [статья](https://laravel.demiart.ru/repository-design-pattern/) для логики репозиторий, о которой я говорил.

Надеюсь смог немного прояснить про сегодняшние тенденции написания кода на `laravel`.